# How to create Gradient overlay above ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, gradient, android-theme

I want to create a **customised action ba**r. Which will be combining the **app theme** colour with the **gradient overlay** to get a new gradient. I have pasted my gradient file and the background colour codes. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="@color/gradient_start_colour"
        android:endColor="@color/gradient_end_colour"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

And theme colour for app is `#0097a7` . Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if yes, how to do it?

Comment: what do you have problems with?

Comment: I am not able to get how to do this? Did you get my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can create drawable like this,

drawable/toolbar_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#0097a7"/>

            <gradient
                android:angle="9"
                android:endColor="#FFF"
                android:startColor="#55FFFFFF"
                android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and in toolbar you can give background like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked. I did not know about layer-list.